# SSRS Temp Data Building

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My question is around the ordering of dataset execution in SSRS. I have a few theories around what I should do, but I would like peoples opinions.

**The situation:** I was asked to look at a report that was running slowly. After looking into the report I noticed that it reused a query multiple times with slightly different where clauses. So I have built a nicely indexed temp table and a stored procedure that builds that. All is working fine and dramatically cuts execution time down.

**The Issue:** Now I have 15 datasets that rather than executing the original large query, does a

> select *

with its own where clause on the temp data.

Now I need to make sure that the stored procedure runs ONCE before all the datasets are then executed. I don't want to add checking to every query or a table to maintain the "Last refreshed" date time of the report data. I should note the stored procedure have parameters in it that come from SSRS. 
What I have considered is:

**A.** Adding an extra parameter to the report that is the final parameter and contingent on all the other parameters having been filled out. This parameter will just call the stored procedure and return a "built date" to be displayed in the parameter page. The issues I see with this, what if a user then changes the first parameter (Which is a date) then will the stored procedure run again with the new parameters or is there a possibility it will never re-execute until the report is loaded again.

**B.** Create the SP as a dataset and then put ordering on the datasets so they have single executions. My issue with this is that ordered execution (Might, im not sure) kill the parallelism of the report executing datasets, which will over all slow the report down.

Has anyone come across this problem before? If so what option did you take, or is there a better on I haven't thought of?

Comment: Why don't you investigate this for all of us and report back? Just monitor the connection to SQL Server and validate (or not) your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I change the mindset around how I would approach this issue slightly.
I tested the dataset ordering and it did kill performance as not only did it execute a single dataset at a time, it also opened and closed the connection each time.

So what I did was changed how my report worked, as each of the datasets was a slightly different query on the temp table being built and the main concern was ordering the build before the datasets kicked off.

So I made a large unioned query in a single stored procedure and added as the first column to each row, the dataset name. This allowed me to have a single dataset, build the temp table at the start of the query and discard it at the end.
With this method I have had to rework the report somewhat, replacing the normal field mappings to use the =lookup function.

But apart from that, the hard work is being off loaded to the SSRS server and I have no more sequencing issues!

Caz

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this properly, each dataset is the same select statement with a different value in the where clause. If so, could you put the select statement in a single dataset and populate the report using a suitable expression, passing a suitable hidden parameter?